# Python stack images into cube

Tags: python, numpy

Is there a fast way to stack images into a cube? I know that you can use np.append to append two, but if there is a lot of them then you need a forloop and a reshape. are there any smarter ways to do it?

Comment: You don't need to reshape, you can access a particular image doing `my_cube[:,:,i]`

Comment: You already have the correct term: stack. There is a function with the same name: [`numpy.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) which takes an arbitrary number of arrays an concatenates them along a new axis.

Example:

```
images = [np.random.randn(8, 12) for _ in range(50)]
stacked =  np.stack(images, axis=0)
print(stacked.shape)  # output: (50, 8, 12)
```